# Blur background when dropdown is opened when using bootstrap dropdown and react

Tags: jquery, css, reactjs, react-bootstrap, blur

I am using **"react-bootstrap": "^1.5.2"** in react.
I want to blur everything except the dropdown when the dropdown is opened but the `:not` selector is not
working and the when applying blur the dropdown is also getting blured which I don't want.

```
const openedDropdowns = $('.dropdown .show')
                if (openedDropdowns.length > 0) {
                    $('body>:not(.dropdown-menu.show>*)').css({
                        '-webkit-filter': 'blur(5px)',
                        '-moz-filter': 'blur(5px)',
                        '-o-filter': 'blur(5px)',
                        '-ms-filter': 'blur(5px)',
                        'filter': 'blur(5px)'
                    })
                }
                else
                    $('body>*').css({
                        '-webkit-filter': 'none',
                        '-moz-filter': 'none',
                        '-o-filter': 'none',
                        '-ms-filter': 'none',
                        'filter': 'none'
                    })
```

Can anyone tell what is problem with this code.

Comment: Can you show you markup?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what your markup looks like, but I'd do something like this.

You have to have a listener for your `Is Dropdown Open`. So it would end up looking something like this.

Also, I'd wrap all content you want blurred in a container. My example uses `<main class="content">`.

Does this help?

```js
const toggleDropdown = $("button.toggle");
const dropdown = $(".dropdown-menu");
const mainContent = $("main.content");

toggleDropdown.click(function () {
  dropdown.toggleClass("show");

  if (dropdown.hasClass("show")) {
    mainContent.css({
      "-webkit-filter": "blur(5px)",
      "-moz-filter": "blur(5px)",
      "-o-filter": "blur(5px)",
      "-ms-filter": "blur(5px)",
      filter: "blur(5px)"
    });
  } else {
    mainContent.css({
      "-webkit-filter": "none",
      "-moz-filter": "none",
      "-o-filter": "none",
      "-ms-filter": "none",
      filter: "none"
    });
  }
});
```

```css
.dropdown-menu {
  width: 100%;
  background: lightblue;
  padding: 20px 12px;
}

main.content {
  transition: .2s;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<button class="toggle">Toggle Dropdown</button>

<div class="dropdown-menu">
  <p>Fake Dropdown Menu</p>
</div>

<main class="content">
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Integer nec odio. Praesent libero. Sed cursus ante dapibus diam. Sed nisi. Nulla quis sem at nibh elementum imperdiet. Duis sagittis ipsum. Praesent mauris. Fusce nec tellus sed augue semper porta. Mauris massa. Vestibulum lacinia arcu eget nulla. Class aptent taciti sociosqu ad litora torquent per conubia nostra, per inceptos himenaeos. Curabitur sodales ligula in libero. Sed dignissim lacinia nunc. </p>

  <p>Curabitur tortor. Pellentesque nibh. Aenean quam. In scelerisque sem at dolor. Maecenas mattis. Sed convallis tristique sem. Proin ut ligula vel nunc egestas porttitor. Morbi lectus risus, iaculis vel, suscipit quis, luctus non, massa. Fusce ac turpis quis ligula lacinia aliquet. Mauris ipsum. Nulla metus metus, ullamcorper vel, tincidunt sed, euismod in, nibh. Quisque volutpat condimentum velit. Class aptent taciti sociosqu ad litora torquent per conubia nostra, per inceptos himenaeos. </p>

  <p>Nam nec ante. Sed lacinia, urna non tincidunt mattis, tortor neque adipiscing diam, a cursus ipsum ante quis turpis. Nulla facilisi. Ut fringilla. Suspendisse potenti. Nunc feugiat mi a tellus consequat imperdiet. Vestibulum sapien. Proin quam. Etiam ultrices. Suspendisse in justo eu magna luctus suscipit. Sed lectus. </p>

  <p>Integer euismod lacus luctus magna. Quisque cursus, metus vitae pharetra auctor, sem massa mattis sem, at interdum magna augue eget diam. Vestibulum ante ipsum primis in faucibus orci luctus et ultrices posuere cubilia Curae; Morbi lacinia molestie dui. Praesent blandit dolor. Sed non quam. In vel mi sit amet augue congue elementum. Morbi in ipsum sit amet pede facilisis laoreet. Donec lacus nunc, viverra nec, blandit vel, egestas et, augue. Vestibulum tincidunt malesuada tellus. Ut ultrices ultrices enim. Curabitur sit amet mauris. Morbi in dui quis est pulvinar ullamcorper. Nulla facilisi. Integer lacinia sollicitudin massa. </p>

  <p>Cras metus. Sed aliquet risus a tortor. Integer id quam. Morbi mi. Quisque nisl felis, venenatis tristique, dignissim in, ultrices sit amet, augue. Proin sodales libero eget ante. Nulla quam. Aenean laoreet. Vestibulum nisi lectus, commodo ac, facilisis ac, ultricies eu, pede. Ut orci risus, accumsan porttitor, cursus quis, aliquet eget, justo. Sed pretium blandit orci. Ut eu diam at pede suscipit sodales. Aenean lectus elit, fermentum non, convallis id, sagittis at, neque. </p>

  <p>Nullam mauris orci, aliquet et, iaculis et, viverra vitae, ligula. Nulla ut felis in purus aliquam imperdiet. Maecenas aliquet mollis lectus. Vivamus consectetuer risus et tortor. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Integer nec odio. Praesent libero. Sed cursus ante dapibus diam. Sed nisi. Nulla quis sem at nibh elementum imperdiet. Duis sagittis ipsum. </p>

  <p>Praesent mauris. Fusce nec tellus sed augue semper porta. Mauris massa. Vestibulum lacinia arcu eget nulla. Class aptent taciti sociosqu ad litora torquent per conubia nostra, per inceptos himenaeos. Curabitur sodales ligula in libero. Sed dignissim lacinia nunc. Curabitur tortor. Pellentesque nibh. Aenean quam. In scelerisque sem at dolor. </p>

  <p>Maecenas mattis. Sed convallis tristique sem. Proin ut ligula vel nunc egestas porttitor. Morbi lectus risus, iaculis vel, suscipit quis, luctus non, massa. Fusce ac turpis quis ligula lacinia aliquet. Mauris ipsum. Nulla metus metus, ullamcorper vel, tincidunt sed, euismod in, nibh. Quisque volutpat condimentum velit. Class aptent taciti sociosqu ad litora torquent per conubia nostra, per inceptos himenaeos. Nam nec ante. Sed lacinia, urna non tincidunt mattis, tortor neque adipiscing diam, a cursus ipsum ante quis turpis. Nulla facilisi. </p>

  <p>Ut fringilla. Suspendisse potenti. Nunc feugiat mi a tellus consequat imperdiet. Vestibulum sapien. Proin quam. Etiam ultrices. Suspendisse in justo eu magna luctus suscipit. Sed lectus. Integer euismod lacus luctus magna. Quisque cursus, metus vitae pharetra auctor, sem massa mattis sem, at interdum magna augue eget diam. Vestibulum ante ipsum primis in faucibus orci luctus et ultrices posuere cubilia Curae; Morbi lacinia molestie dui. Praesent blandit dolor. </p>

  <p>Sed non quam. In vel mi sit amet augue congue elementum. Morbi in ipsum sit amet pede facilisis laoreet. Donec lacus nunc, viverra nec, blandit vel, egestas et, augue. Vestibulum tincidunt malesuada tellus. Ut ultrices ultrices enim. Curabitur sit amet mauris. Morbi in dui quis est pulvinar ullamcorper. Nulla facilisi. Integer lacinia sollicitudin massa. Cras metus. Sed aliquet risus a tortor. Integer id quam. </p>
</main>
```

Comment: When I inspect dropdown elements they show me that the element has **filter of none**, but I can still see the blur on them.

Comment: My code, I think It is because my dropdown is in a bootstrap table, because when i blur other elements which is not inside the table then the blur applies correctly.

Comment: Could you post your code on jsbin, codesandbox or codepen?